# Where does Window 10 keep its geolocation data? Is it possible to change them from cmd/powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, geolocation

So the problem is: there are a few laptops at some distance from the office. Some of them detect their geolocation absolutely correctly, some not. The question: is it possible to replace the geolocation data detected by Windows 10 with the data got from some web site that correctly detect those data using cmd or powershell?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As far as I am aware the public IP address is used for geolocation and the accuracy will vary. 2 examples - I work from home and remote into a server in Glasgow (nowhere near my actual location) which is where it thinks I'm located. My laptop uses mobile tethering and it thinks it is located where my ISP DNS is located, again nowhere near my actual location.

Answer (score 0):

You can only manually set your device's **Default** location. If better location sources are available, then those will override the manual setting:

> To change the default location for your PC, which Windows, apps, and services can use when a more exact location can’t be detected:
>
> - Go to Start   > Settings  > Privacy  > Location.
> - Under Default location, select Set default.
> - The Windows Maps app will open. Follow the instructions to change your default location.

Microsoft has more detail written up here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-location-service-and-privacy-3a8eee0a-5b0b-dc07-eede-2a5ca1c49088

---

Some services use your microsoft account's "Home Location" instead, and this can be set with powershell's [Set-WinHomeLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winhomelocation), and you can view the current setting with `Get-WinHomeLocation`